# Cannot find module 'date-fns-tz' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-redux, date-fns

"Cannot find module 'date-fns-tz' or its corresponding type declarations."

Anyone had this problem before ? I have installed the date-fns package.

`import { zonedTimeToUtc, utcToZonedTime } from 'date-fns-tz';`

Comment: Have you installed `date-fns-tz` as well?

Answer (score 1):

Hey @kacper did you try this command-

```
npm i @types/date-fns-tz
```

or

```
yard add @types/date-fns-tz
```

some packages have already defined their libraries (@types/module-name) you can add this also, so that you will allow typescript to check types declaration.

But the main thing is you should have to first install main library package i.e. date-fns-tz.

If you still facing issue let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: update to `date-fns-tz@2.0.0` to get the correct type exports.

---

**Explanation**:

I ran into this issue when moving a project over to ES modules. `data-fns-tz` included types and ESM exports as of 1.3.x but had ESM-specific paths, e.g., `data-fns-tz/esm/format`.

Node.js and TypeScript now pick up the correct module at runtime based on the `type` property. So, if your project has `"type": "module"` in its `package.json` then the runtime will know to pull the ESM files based on the dependencies package exports.

`data-fns-tz` had separate imports for CommonJS and ESM, so the types didn't flow through automatically.

[Here's the relevant PR](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz/commit/455640ffcd8e1301456200f6bc664b077d3d8953) that changes the export pattern in the package so the runtime will pick up the relevant files based on the module format set in `type`.

Read more about the type field [here](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type).